# puts() output is appended "time" string

Tags: c, getchar, puts

I get very unexpected output from quite simple code

```
char ch = getchar(), word[100], *p = word;

while (ch != '\n') {
    *(p++) = ch;
    ch = getchar();
}
puts(word);
```

output of any 17 character input is appended by "time" like

```
12345678901234567time
```

if exceeds "time" is overwritten like

```
1234567890123456789me
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It's not [`\0`-terminated](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm)

Comment: The word "time" is just what's left over in the memory occupied by `word`, it's a complete coincidence.

Comment: `getchar` returns an `int`, not a `char` intentionally!

Comment: @Iamnotgoodatfindingname: can you accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`puts` expects a pointer to `string`. And a `string` needs to have a terminating `null character` - `\0` - to signify where the string ends.

But in your case, you did not write the `\0` at the end to signify that the string ends there.

You need to do:

```
char ch = getchar(), word[100], *p = word;

/* Also check that you are not writing more than 100 chars */
int i = 1;
while(ch != '\n' && i++ < 100){  
    *(p++) = ch; 
    ch = getchar();
}
*p = '\0'; /* write the terminaring null character */
puts(word);
```

Before, when you were not writing the terminating null character you could not expect anything determinate to print. It could also have been `12345678901234567AnyOtherWord` or something.

Comment: `0` works just as well as `'\0'`. I only mention it in case you come across it in other code.

Comment: Recommend `int ch = getchar() ... while(ch != '\n' && ch != EOF && i++ < 100){`

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues in your code:

- You do not null terminate the string you pass to `puts()`, invoking undefined behavior... in your case, whatever characters happen to be present in `word` after the last one read from `stdin` are printed after these and until (hopefully) a `'\0'` byte is finally found in memory.
- You read a byte from `stdin` into a `char` variable: this does not allow you to check for `EOF`, and indeed you do not.
- If you read a long line, you will write bytes beyond the end if the `word` array, invoking undefined behavior.  If the end of file is encountered before a `'\n'` is read from `stdin`, you will definitely write beyond the end of the buffer...  Try for example giving an empty file as input for your program.

Here is a corrected version:

```
char word[100];
char *p = word;
int ch;

while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n') {
    /* check for long line: in this case, we truncate the line */
    if (p < word + sizeof(word) - 1) {
        *p++ = ch;
    }
}
*p = '\0';
puts(word);
```

Comment: Nice line consumption and `EOF` check.